# copy lane from different sheet if the same value

Tags: vba, excel

I have 5 columns in sheet1, and the same in sheet 2.The name of the product is in A. But sometimes the caracteristics of the products (in B,C,D,E) can change in sheet 2. I want that it actualize the caracteristics in Sheet1.

I tried a Vlookup, but it works only zith one Cell

```
Sub test()
With Sheets("Feuil1")
    .Range("B1").Value = WorksheetFunction.VLookup(.Range("A1").Value, Sheets("Feuil2").Range("A1:B100"), 2, False)
End With
End Sub
```

Moreover, I cant copy all the line because the colomn F should not change… And products in sheet1 in column A are not tidy and get some duplicates...

Comment: It may be that `VLookup` isn't working because your range in `Feuil2` isn't listed alphabetically.

Comment: My Vlookup is working, but just with one cell, or I want that it copy B,C,D,E.... but not the last cell. In each line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a loop for this to update each row and you need to update each column as well.

I recommend to use [WorksheetFunction.Match](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/Excel.WorksheetFunction.Match) instead so you only need to match once per row to get the row number and then you can copy the desired values of that row.

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub UpdateData()
    Dim WsDest As Worksheet 'destination workbook to write in
    Set WsDest = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Feuil1")

    Dim WsSrc As Worksheet 'source workbook to match with
    Set WsSrc = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Feuil2")

    Dim LastRow As Long 'last used row in workbook
    LastRow = WsDest.Cells(WsDest.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

    Dim iRow As Long, MatchedRow As Long
    For iRow = 1 To LastRow 'loop through all rows from row 1 to last used row and update each row
        MatchedRow = 0 'initialize
        On Error Resume Next 'if no match found then ignore error
        MatchedRow = WorksheetFunction.Match(WsDest.Cells(iRow, "A"), WsSrc.Columns("A"), 0) 'get the row number of the match
        On Error GoTo 0 'reactivate error reporting

        'if it didn't match then MatchedRow is still 0

        If MatchedRow > 0 Then 'if a match was found then copy values
            WsDest.Cells(iRow, "B").Value = WsSrc.Cells(MatchedRow, "B").Value
            WsDest.Cells(iRow, "C").Value = WsSrc.Cells(MatchedRow, "C").Value
            WsDest.Cells(iRow, "D").Value = WsSrc.Cells(MatchedRow, "D").Value
            WsDest.Cells(iRow, "E").Value = WsSrc.Cells(MatchedRow, "E").Value
        Else
            'didn't find a match
            'you can remove the Else part if you want to do nothing here
        End If
    Next iRow
End Sub
```

If the columns you want to copy are continous like B, C, D, E you can do it in one copy action which is faster than 4 copy actions (1 for each column):

```
WsDest.Range("B" & iRow & ":E" & iRow).Value = WsSrc.Range("B" & MatchedRow & ":E" & MatchedRow).Value
```

Comment: Exactly what I wanted to do ! It works even on Mac. Didnt knew about the Match fonction, TY.